# Is there any Way to create Personal library of Vue UI components that can be shared with teams?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shared-libraries, bit, vue-cli-3

### I want to create personal repository of Vue UI components like git,npm,git provides, I want to do it using Own Repository from git and install component across any project

### Steps Can be like these:

- 1)Create  UI component in Vue js
- 2) Packaging of UI component like Npm,Git,Bit
- 3) Push on git,bitbucket
- 4) Pull and install the component in any project

Comment: You could always use git submodules

Comment: Yes. You can do EXACTLY this.